# Adding ShowcaseView as library project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, showcaseview

How can I add the ShowcaseView project as a library to my project?

I´m using Eclipse [ADT].
I´ve already set the checkbox "is libryry" in properties from the library to checked and added it to my library but the example code

```
    new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
    .setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))
    .setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
    .setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button")
    .hideOnTouchOutside()
    .build();
```

says "Create class 'ShowcaseView'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to ShowcaseView's project properties in Eclipse
2. Java Build Path
3. source tab
4. add folder
5. select java folder